# Could the Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet recover and start spending UTXOs by only scanning the UTXO set?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, output-script-descriptors, wallet-import, rescan

In the case where you import a previously used BIP32 seed into a Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet, at the moment if I understand correctly, the only way to recover the UTXOs and spend them is by first calling the `rescanblockchain` RPC call. This can be quite time consuming, and requires all the blocks of the UTXOs' transactions to not be pruned.

Could the Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet use the `scantxoutset` call to get a similar outcome? I understand that this would fail to get the full transaction history of the BIP32 seed, but would this call be enough to just recover the wallet's current balance, and make valid transactions?